# How to create a maven jar with out including all the dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I want to create a util jar ( 80KB) using Maven project. This Jar has dependency on apache.poi.jar, apache.poi-api.jar, apache commons-lang3.jar  and few other. These are available in Maven central repository and I provided them as dependency in pom of util project.

Note: This jar is not a runnable jar with main class. It will be used by other teams and include as dependency. We have all artifacts added in remote repository

When I create a jar, I don't want to add dependencies inside util jar and make it a fat jar  ( 4 MB).

When users include this jar as dependency, I want the using application to download downstream dependencies and they can package in their WAR.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.test.proj</groupId>
<artifactId>util</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In the packaged jar, Is there a possibility to include the dependencies as POM and maven will read this and download them also.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Not including the dependencies in the JAR file is the _default behavior_. And if you've published to a Maven repository (e.g., Maven Central), then when other projects declare your project as a dependency then the declared dependencies of your project become _transitive dependencies_.

Comment: @Slaw We don't publish to maven central. We place them in remote repository and where should  I declare the dependencies ?

Comment: Maven Central was only an example (hence the "e.g." and the parentheses). And you declare dependencies in the POM like normal.

Comment: @Slaw I was doing mvn package. Once I did mvn install, I could see the pom file with dependencies.

Comment: Please show the full POM in the question text. As Slaw said, the behaviour you want is the default, so something in the POM must be changing that.

Comment: Usually you dont create a fat jar without specific pom to build it (e.g. jar-with-dependencies). try looking for this part and disable it. Otherwise you can specify "provided" under scope for your dependencies